# What is the difference between these sentences? (过 vs 了)

Tags: grammar, particles

What is the difference between:

> 你最近看过电视吗？
>
> 你最近看了电视吗？

and

> 你最近去过杂货店吗？
>
> 你最近去了杂货店吗？

And similarly, if I want to say "recently I went to my favourite cinema and found it's closed down" would I say 我最近去了我最喜欢的电影院，可是发现了它已经关闭了? Or should the first and second 了s be omitted? I know that this 了 means "action completed" but I've seen many example sentences where actions are completed yet there is no 了, which has left me confused about when I should include it.

Comment: for more  information in English search web using e.g.  "Chinese grammar，了 & 过", in particular see ＂Using "guo" with "le" （C Grammar Wiki）

Comment: The 1st 了 *could* be omitted, the 2nd 了 (the one after 发现) *should* be omitted. Sorry I can't give a strict rule for this (as a native speaker).

Comment: re:when not to use 了 see http://www.ctcfl.ox.ac.uk/Grammar%20exercises/LE1.htm  11. Apart from the negation, are there any circumstances in which 了 is not used (for completed actions)?

Answer (score 1):

In casual conversation without further context, sentences in the first two groups are almost the same.  If no additional information is available, both expressions are acceptable to a native speaker. But using "过" is still better.

"了" vs. "过" :

"你最近看过电视吗？" means "did you watch TV **at least once** recently."  The time, TV program and duration of the action "watching TV" is **not** being asked.

"你最近看了电视吗？" means "have you watched TV recently".  And "了" here implies that "watching TV" is **finished/done**.  It is used when talking about the consequence of the action.

The translation of the last sentence in your question ("recently I went to my favorite cinema and found it's closed down") is acceptable.  But it is better to omit that "了" after "发现".

"发现了" is used when a noun is after "发现了". Example: "X发现了新大陆", "X found new continent".  But when a sentence with "了" is used after "发现了", then you can omit "了" in "发现了".